# Exclude part of R markdown documents based on output document type

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to render  part of an Rmarkdown document only for a specific output?

For example, I would like to use the same analysis both to write a report and a presentation.

I would like to be able to have some part of the document only to be rendered when the output is `html_document`, but not when the output is `slidy_presentation`; I do not mean necessarily a chunk of code, but text too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter the action depending on document, using `rmarkdown.pandoc.to`.  Regarding text, I don't know another way than embedding that text into a code chunk.

```
my_output <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")

if (my_output=="html"){
    cat('<h2>My header</h2>\n')
} else {
    cat('## My header\n')
}


if (my_output == "latex"){
  opts_chunk$set(dev='cairo_pdf', dev.args=list(cairo_pdf = list(family='Times New Roman')))
}
```